# IsString instance not automatically converted to String

Tags: string, haskell, typeclass

I have a type `a` which is an instance of the `IsString` typeclass.

If I use something like

```
"foobar" :: a
```

everything works fine.

As soon as I use a function that returns a string, as in

```
("foo" ++ "bar") :: a
```

I get a compilation error telling me that

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
Expected type: a
Actual type: String
```

Notice that I have the `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` pragma.

Is there something else I should do to solve the compilation error?

Comment: `IsString` does not mean you can apply all kinds of operations with it. It only means that we can convert a `String` to it, and that by enabling the pragma, we can write literals that we then will transparently convert to such objects.

Comment: do you mean that `IsString` works only with hardcoded strings? And not with any value which is actually a string?

Comment: but `a` is not actually a `String`. You can however use `fromString` to cast the result of `"foo" ++ "bar"` to a `String`.

Comment: `"foo" ++ "bar"` already is a `String`. I can use `fromString` to cast from `String` to `a`, but I hoped this to happen automatically

Comment: no, as far as I know it only works for `String` literals. This is probably desirable as well, since otherwise this would result in implicit type conversions, and this could result in rather undefined behavior. Since if we would generalize that, and we have an `a`, and we implicitly want to cast it to a `d`, and there are two ways to do it (for instance by `f1 :: a -> b` and `f2 :: b -> d`, and `g1 :: a -> c` and `g2 :: c -> d`), then what should the compiler pick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of the [**`IsString`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) typeclass is to specify that we can convert a `String` object to such object (with the **`fromString :: String -> a`** function). Furthermore by enabling the `OverloadedStrings` pragma, we can also write `a` objects as string literals (in that case these `String` *literals* will transparently be converted to `a`s by calling the `fromString` function).

Note however that `IsString` does *not* results in a way to convert `a`s back to `String`s. Furthermore functions that are defined on `String`s can *not* be used for such instances (at least not without doing some implementation work).

If you write:

```
("foo" ++ "bar") :: a
```

Haskell will derive that you call `(++) :: [b] -> [b] -> [b]`, so as a result it knows that the type of these string literals is a `IsString [b] => [b]`. So that means that `a ~ [b]`. Since your type is probably not a list, there is no way that this can match.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now it kind of makes sense. It just feels weird that `"777" :: a` works and `show 777 :: a` doesn't, since in both cases the compiler is converting `[Char]` to `a`. In other terms, the fact that the code compiles or not, does not depends just on the types of the expressions... isn't this against equational resoning?

Comment: The way string constants work with `OverloadedStrings` is sort of like how numeric constants work.  The constant `1` is overloaded and means `fromIntegral 1`, so you can use integer *constants* for any type of `Num`, defaulting to `Integer`. Similarly, you can use a string *constant* for any type of `IsString`, defaulting to `String`. However, that does not mean you can implicitly convert any `Integer` expression to any `Num` without an explicit call to `fromIntegral`. Likewise for srings. (Some other languages, such as C++, do provide such implicit conversions.)

Comment: If you want to do this, the easiest way ts to define a conversion function, such as `Data.ByteString.pack`.  So, after the right `import qualified`, `B.pack ("foo" ++ "bar")` would get you your `ByteString`. However, it will often be more efficient to reimplement functions for your new type (or else why have it?), so you would more likely write `B.append "foo" "bar"`, and the compiler can then infer the correct types for the arguments.